# Jquery UI Resizable with helper adds positioning in firefox

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox

I'm using jquery UI to resize a div vertically(I.E. using the n handle). I'm using a helper so it only resizes after the user stops dragging. After a resize is done I call a function which sets dimensions on surrounding elements so they all fit within a container.

This works in both chrome and IE, but in firefox a css property of top is added which blows the div out of the container.

I've tried removing the top value after the fact, which works, but this is kind of a hack and also causes the div to 'jump'.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround using jquery css html, etc?

To see what I mean check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lchamberlain/bqGwW/1/) fiddle and resize the element, if you inspect it in firefox there will a top css property but not in chrome.

Thanks,
Luke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion it is a bug.

Workaround: if you add a `top: 0;` to the css rule for `#resizable` IE, chrome and firefox have the same behavior. Also see the [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/bqGwW/2/).

=== UPDATE ===

It's a firefox bug. I walked from the jQuery UI *resizable* method code until the *css* method of jQuery (main) code to find an answer. At the end of my search I could found that firefox returns for css `top` value `auto` for not/static positioned elements, but returns `0px` if relative position is set; in both cases `top` is not defined (they could be set to `auto` with no difference - it's the default value).

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jHnSu/2/).

In the *resizable* method this result makes the difference (jQuery UI sets the relative position to the DOM element by adding a class). If the bug (which I have reported to mozilla) will be fixed, the behavior of your example in the firefox should be the same as in chrome.

I'll report here if there is something new...

=== UPDATE ===

Now I have a workaround for you:

for the special situation you described set the css position of your resizable element manually to `static`.

Add to your stylesheets:

```
#resizable { position: static; }
```

Also see [your updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/bqGwW/4/).

Comment: Thanks! Having them all work the same is a significant improvement, but I would rather have firefox behave as IE and chrome to prevent a rewrite of my code.

Comment: That's great! It looks like that should work with very little changes to my inplace code. Thanks for the help and thank you for reporting the bug.